# Suddenly getting 403 from YouTube data-API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am suddenly getting a 403 error when sending requests to YouTube's data-API.

This is the error I am getting in production for all requests:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 944988770273 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=944988770273 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=944988770273"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 944988770273 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=944988770273 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

I haven't done anything do disable the keys, and the dashboard still says the project and key is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to YouTube setting my daily limit to 0 for some reason, effectively "banning" the usage on the current project in use.

If this happens error-message happens to anyone, remember to check the quotas for the project.

Answer (score 1):

[I filled an issue on Youtube Bug Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157409583) related to it. The feedback was:

*This means that your project’s access to YouTube Data API Service has been disabled.
Please fill out and submit the exceptions form below: https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en*

No reasons why.