# YouTube Data API stopped working with "accessNotConfigured" error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have been using the same Google Cloud project and API key for accessing YouTube Data API v3 for quite some time. Today, all requests started to fail with the following error:

```
{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project PROJECT_ID before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=PROJECT_ID then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=PROJECT_ID"
}
```

However, the YouTube Data API v3 has always been enabled and working until today. We also see a daily quota of 0 in the Quotas page and cannot change it.

Has anything changed recently? Not sure what we could try to get it working again.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248495/suddenly-getting-403-from-youtube-data-api/59658625#59658625) apparently youtube has restricted your project from using the present API key try regenerating new API key or create a new project and generate new key.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried using another API Key from another project that was already created with no luck (the same error is returned). Should I try to create a new project from scratch?